# Webpack: Generating two different files for the same js file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I new to webpack. I am using node.js as a server and want to server send file as a response. For route `/` I want to send `index.html`, for route `/other` I want to send `other.html`, and so on...

At the moment all html files calls js files using `<script>`. For example, `index.html` contains `<script src='../index.js'></script>`.

Few days ago I was introduced with webpack. My webpack config is as following

```js
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const commonHtmlPluginProps = {
   inject: false,
   minify: {
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      minifyJS: true,
      removeComments: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      sortClassName: true
   }
}

module.exports = {
   mode: 'production',
   entry: {
      // index: './src/index.js',
      // another: './src/another.js',
      // other: './src/other.js',

      index: './src/html/index.html',
      another: './src/html/another.html',
      other: './src/html/other.html',

   },
   plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'html', 'index.html'),
         ouptutName: 'index.html',
         ...commonHtmlPluginProps,
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'html', 'another.html'),
         filename: 'another.html',
         ...commonHtmlPluginProps,
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'html', 'other.html'),
         filename: 'other.html',
         ...commonHtmlPluginProps,
      }),
   ],
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: ['html-loader']
         }
      ],
   },

   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].js'
   },
}
```

and I have following file structure

[image: dir structure]

Whenever I rebuild the project I get two copies of js files, even though my entry is from html files.

Where I am mistaken? Suggest me a better way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can config `html-webpack-plugin` to add only some chunks, like `chunks: ["index"],`, no need to use script tag in html template

Comment: @Livio I tried your suggestion, then I will have to add scripts manually, right?

Comment: set `inject: true`, the script should be inject into html autoly

Comment: Yes I tried with it and it seems what I wanted! Thanks a lot!